# Getting the current index in the input string (flex lexer)

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I am using flex lexer. Is there a way to (1) get the current index in the input string (2) jump back to that index in a future time point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly easy to maintain the current input position. When any rule is matched, `yyleng` contains the length of the match, so it is sufficient to add `yyleng` to the cumulative length processed. Assuming you are using flex, it is not necessary to insert the code directly into every rule action, which would be tedious. Instead, you can use the `YY_USER_ACTION` macro:

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION input_pos += yyleng;
```

(This assumes that you have defined `input_pos` somewhere, and arranged for it to be initialized to 0 when the lexical scan commences.)

This will lead to incorrect results if you use `REJECT`, `yymore()`, `yyless()` or `input()`; in all of these cases, you will have to adjust the value of `input_pos`. For every call to `yymore()`, you need to subtract `yyleng` from `input_pos`; this will also work for `REJECT`. For a call to `yyless()`, you can subtract `yyleng` before the call and add it back after the call. For each call to `input()`, you need to add one to `input_pos`.

Within a rule, you can then use `input_pos` as the position at the *end* of the match, or `input_pos - yyleng` as the position at the beginning of the match.

Returning to a saved position is trickier.

(F)lex does not maintain the entire input in memory, so in principle you would need to use `fseek()` to rewind `yyin` to the correct place. However, in the common case where `yyin` has not been opened in binary mode, you cannot reliably use `fseek()` to return to a computed input offset. So at a minimum, you would have to ensure that `yyin` was opened (or reopened) in binary mode.

Moreover, it is not in general possible to guarantee that whatever stream `yyin` is attached to can be rewound at all (it might be console input, a pipe, or some other non-seekable device). So to be fully general, you might have to use a temporary file to store data read from the stream. This will create additional complications when you attempt to reread previous input, because you will have to switch to the temporary file for reading until it is finished, at which point you would have to return to the main file. Creative use of `yywrap` will simplify this procedure.

Note that after you rewind the input stream -- whether or not you switch to reading from a temporary file -- you must call `yyrestart()` to reset the scanner's input buffer. (This is also a flex-only feature; Posix lex does not specify the mechanism by which you inform the scanner that its buffer needs to be reset, so if you are not using flex you will have to consult the relevant documentation for your scanner generator.)